# Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() - how to see how many tasks are in queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() in my code. 
I want to monitor number of tasks in queue to check that procesor is not overloaded with messages. How can I get a number of not completed submited tasks for curent moment?
I expect something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(new Runnable() {...});
executor.submit(new Runnable() {...});
executor.submit(new Runnable() {...});
// do something and get 3
...
// do something and get 2
...
// do something and get 1
```

Thanks

Comment: And I quote, _no more than one task will be active at any given time_. However, you can check if the currently submitted has run to completion by calling `isDone()` on the returned `Future`.

Comment: here http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29

Comment: "I want to monitor number of tasks in queue to check that procesor is not overloaded with messages" And if it is what are you going to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case you want to guarantee that even with new versions of the JVM the code suggested by FlorianOver will work, you could do it this way: (For the case that the method Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() will no longer return an instance of type ThreadPoolExecutor)

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

// ...

int queueSize = executor.getQueue().size();
```

Comment: +1, always code to the interface. All of the utility methods in `Executors` return the interface type `ExecutorService` or `ScheduledExecutorService` therefore the implementation of `Executors` makes no guarantee that what is returned will extend from any specific implementation (even if there is only one publicly available implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it like this?

```
((ThreadPoolExecutor) executor).getQueue().size();
```

Comment: -1, Wrong. This will cause a `ClassCastException` as the `ExecutorService` implementation returned by `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` is a `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` and not a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (since Java 6).